# Count same column from same table with different conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using SQL on GBQ.

Here is a simplified version of my table :

```
Number | Amount | Name
 4        10       A
 1         0       B
 6        100      A
 8         0       C
 5         0       A
 4        10       C
```

None of the fields "Number", "Amount" or "Name" have unique values.
They all can be repeated many times.

I want to calculate the occurrences where each "Name" has Amount=0 divided by the Total occurrence of that Name.
Like the following : Count(Amount=0)/Count(Total)

For example :

- For A : 1/3 = 0.33
- For B : 1/1 = 1
- For C : 1/2 = 0.5

To have the total occurrences by "Name", I could do the following query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Total, Name
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name
```

To count Amount=0 for each "Name" :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) TotalZero, Name
FROM MyTable
WHERE Amount>0
GROUP BY Name
```

How can I get both Total and TotalZero columns as a result of 1 query, to be able to divide them ?

I tried the following query :

```
SELECT A.TotalZero/A.Total 
FROM
   (SELECT COUNT(*) Total, Name
    FROM MyTable) A ,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) TotalZero, Name
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Amount>0) B
GROUP BY A.Name
```

But I need a column to join the 2 tables on and I am not sure which one I should use.
Any help would be useful.

**Note** : The table in my example above is actually the result of a sub-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is `countif()`:

```
SELECT Name, COUNTIF(Amount = 0) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name;
```

Another method is conditional aggregation using `AVG()`:

```
SELECT Name, AVG(CASE WHEN Amount = 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It didn't work because COUNTIF(Amount=0) always returns 0 for all 'Names'.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the table is a subquery. Could that be the reason ?

Comment: @HelpASisterOut . . . if `countif()` returns `0`, then there are no cases where `amount = 0`.  Whether you are querying from a table or subquery doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes indeed it was a problem in my subquery - works now thanks !